# Javascript calling $(document).on('click', when document ready

Tags: javascript

I need some help please. The function below works well with an 'up' and 'down' button on a html form.

I want to call this function simulating clicking the 'down' button when the page has finished loading. I don't know how to do this in my $(document).ready(function ()).

Searching here and elsewhere has not provided me any help.

Note that not all the code is shown, so please don't point out errors about undeclared vars thanks.

```
$(document).on('click', '.sig-spinner button', function () {
    var minval = Math.max(<?php echo $qty_sig_all; ?>,5);
    var btn = $(this),
        oldValue = btn.closest('.sig-spinner').find('input').val().trim(),
        newVal = 0;
    if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
        newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        if (oldValue > minval) {
            newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = minval;
        }
    }
    btn.closest('.sig-spinner').find('input').val(newVal);
    document.getElementById("sigtot").innerHTML = '$' + newVal + '.00';
    sigval = newVal;
    totval = sigval + smsval;
    document.getElementById("ordertot").innerHTML = '$' + totval + '.00';
    gstval = (totval - (totval / 1.1)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("gsttot").innerHTML = '$' + gstval;
});
```

Comment: thisOneGuy, Haha, where did you learn to read? Where did I say it's all shown? (I specifically said 'not all the code is shown' on the last line.

Comment: haha obviously i still haven't learnt :L my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.sig-spinner button', function () {
    ...
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sig-spinner button').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you. I think that is what I am looking for, but how do I send a command (simulate clicking the down button, or not the up button in the if statement starting on line 6 of the code)?

Comment: I think I understand, and my comment above is not relevant. Because I am NOT sending the 'down' button click, the code I want to run will actually run becuase it doesn't see the 'up' button. Will test and reply soon. Thank you. Ok, so I just tried it and it doesn't work the way I want. It seems to active the 'up' button.

Comment: Not working. How do I set the "btn.attr('data-dir')" in the answer?

Comment: You set attributes like this; btn.attr('data-dir', newAttr); where newAttr is the new value to set

Comment: Thanks Matthew, your answer is getting me closer to a working solution, but how/where do I implement your code example in the answer above? Does it get added to the end of the line, or is it a new line?

Comment: It wants to go OUTSIDE your click function, as you shouldn't be triggering a click inside the click event (See my edit above)

Comment: Are you looking for the 'touchstart' event?

Comment: Thanks again Matthew, greatly appreciated, but sorry I still don't quite understand. I do understand your edit, and that will call my function on document ready. What I dont understand is where do I put the btn.attr('data-dir', newAttr); in your example? Do I simply add that line before the $('.sig-spinner ..... or does it need to be wrapped in somehow?

Comment: Well it depends - when do you want that attribute set to occur exactly?